# Windows text editor with cells

Tags: windows, text-editor, spreadsheet

Is there text editor which treats letters and unoccupied space as cells and allows to copy any rectangular area to any place? Somewhat like Excel, but with one cell for letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text editors **[SynWrite](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** (Windows) and **CudaText** (cross platform) can do this.
In these, you have "column selection mode", Alt+mouse drag. which selects rect block.

[image]

Note: To select also end of lines (where caret cannot go), turn on option "caret_after_end" in CudaText (and "Allow caret after end of line" in SynWrite).

Comment: Only on lines which already in file, not on new lines, but thanks nevertheless.

Comment: It is for lines already in file, not after end.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) can do [rectangular selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729s2dhh(v=vs.100).aspx) of text when holding down the Alt and Shift keys.

[image: Rectangular selection of text in Visual Studio]

Microsoft provides a free community version.

Answer (score 1):

[AkelPad](http://akelpad.sourceforge.net/) and Scintilla-based editors ([Geany](https://www.geany.org/), [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) also support column mode editing (rectangular selections), activated by Alt + Shift + Arrows or Alt + Mouse selection.